# TextView text alignment to center

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to align text inside `TextView` to the center. I used `android:gravity="center"` but it leaves extra spacing between words.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextDarkGrey"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="INTRO TITLE"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextLightGrey"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
            labore et dolore magna aliqua."/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Can u share what is  your expected output

Comment: Have you tried `android:textAlignment="center"`?

Comment: "ut labore" Are these the word that is giving space between them.

Comment: Yep, text will be random and It should be aligned around center, same as in MS Word is alignment to center. This LinearLayout is only part of the whole layout, there will be stuff above it (see weight)

Comment: That is because of the spacing issue. You can remove all the spaces between those two words and give a single space and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you see spacing between words is the extra line you are using for the text, which is introducing spaces between `incididunt ut` and `labore et`.

Just replace this (two lines):

```xml
android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
            labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

With this (one line):

```xml
android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the text of the TextView has to be fixed then just eliminate any new line breaks, otherwise if you want to do this programmatically you can just make sure you won't pass a string with line breaks:

```
TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);
String sampleString = "Line 1\nLine 2";
text.setText(sampleString.replace("\n", " "));
```